# How to write Junit test class for code coverage

Tags: java, junit, mockito, code-coverage

Can someone help me writing JUnit for the below serviceImpl class

```
@Component
public class ProcessStatusMasterServiceImpl implements ProcessStatusMasterService {
  @Autowired
  private ProcessStatusRepository processStatusRepository;
  
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  
  public ProcessAndMacroStatus findProcessMaster(StatusConstant statusConstants) {
    ProcessStatusMasterService thisBean = (ProcessStatusMasterService)this.applicationContext.getBean(ProcessStatusMasterService.class);
    List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatuses = thisBean.findProcessMasterByCategory(statusConstants.getCategory());
    Optional<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatusOpt = processStatuses.stream().filter(f -> f.getProcessAndMacroStatusKey().equals(statusConstants.getKey())).findFirst();
    if (processStatusOpt.isPresent())
      return processStatusOpt.get(); 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find status: " + statusConstants.getKey() + " for category: " + statusConstants.getCategory());
  }
  
  @Cacheable({"ProcessStatusMasterCache"})
  public List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> findProcessMasterByCategory(String category) {
    List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatuses = this.processStatusRepository.findByProcessMacroStatusCategory(category);
    return processStatuses;
  }
}
```

below is the code i am trying, but i am getting NPE for line `when(thisBean.findProcessMasterByCategory(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS.getCategory())).thenReturn(processStatuses);`

Reason for this variable thisbean is null

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProcessStatusMasterServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    ProcessStatusRepository processStatusRepository;

    @Mock
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @InjectMocks
    ProcessStatusMasterServiceImpl processStatusMasterServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void findProcessMaster() throws Exception {
        ProcessStatusMasterService thisBean = (ProcessStatusMasterService)this.applicationContext.getBean(ProcessStatusMasterService.class);
        List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatuses=new ArrayList<ProcessAndMacroStatus>();
        when(thisBean.findProcessMasterByCategory(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS.getCategory())).thenReturn(processStatuses);

        processStatusMasterServiceImpl.findProcessMaster(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: One tip to avoid unnecessary if-else statements on Optionals from Java 8 and higher: you can simply `return processStatusOpt.orElseThrow(...)` see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to mock the behaviour of the tested entity itself instead of the mocked dependencies. I'd try mocking it like this:

```
@Test
public void findProcessMaster() throws Exception {
    List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatuses=new ArrayList<ProcessAndMacroStatus>();
    when(processStatusRepository.findProcessMasterByCategory(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS.getCategory())).thenReturn(processStatuses);

    processStatusMasterServiceImpl.findProcessMaster(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS);
    
}
```

Comment: This too give NPE exception because in serviceImpm class, thisbean is still null. Below is the line ProcessStatusMasterService thisBean = (ProcessStatusMasterService)this.applicationContext.getBean(ProcessStatusMasterService.class);

Comment: thisBean should be deleted, in my example it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your `thisBean` in your production code, just use `this.` instead.

```java
List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatuses = this.findProcessMasterByCategory(statusConstants.getCategory());
```

and modify your test

```java
@Test
public void findProcessMaster() throws Exception {
    List<ProcessAndMacroStatus> processStatuses = new ArrayList<ProcessAndMacroStatus> ();
    when(processStatusRepository.findProcessMasterByCategory(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS.getCategory())).thenReturn(processStatuses);

    processStatusMasterServiceImpl.findProcessMaster(StatusConstant.GROUP_STATUS_SUCCESS);

    // your assert
}
```